# Unable to use jQuery in the javascript function that define in external js

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, import

::SOLVED::

I have an index.php and I define some JavaScript function for do some thing in this page. I use jQuery in this functions. When I put the functions in the index.php between  tags all thing work good but I need to put this functions in external is file. When I do it and then import it in index.php, the js file load and the part that don't use jQuery, work good but the jQuery actions not work! I have put the jQuery before is in head of index.php.  the jQuery load and I test it by simple alert. I tried to put $(function).ready() surrounding the js function and other time surrounding the function content but it doesn't work!

```
<script language='javascript' src="/js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript' src="/js/external.js"></script>
```

And external js file like this:

```
function doSomething(){
//some JavaScript code that work good
//some jQuery code that doesn't work!
}
```

Where is wrong?!
Excuse me for my stupid question!

Answer (score 0):

First of all write better HTML code.

```html
<script src="/js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script> 
<script src="/js/external.js"></script>
```

```js
function doSomething(){
  console.log("I'm executed");
  if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {  
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
  } else {
    console.log("jQuery library not loaded check your Network tab");
  }
}
```

Then seems your jQuery not loaded check your [network tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) for loaded scripts.

Comment: There was some error in parameters! I have used form php in jQuery! Now problem is solved. Thanks.